# AD - transfer operation master

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2003, domain-controller

Our environment has two domains under the same forest, and two way trust been setup between these two domain (sorry, i'm not very savvy about AD, might be using wrong terminology. I try to be as accurate as possible)

Coz one of the domain is still using Windows 2003 as domain controller, so i'm about to build a Windows 2008 R2 server, do a dcpromo on it and hoping to transfer all roles on the old Win2003 DC to the new 2008 DC.

So my question is whether there is any risk during the transfer of these roles (RID operation master, PDC operation master, infrastructure operation master, and AD Domains and Trust operation master) ?   If anything goes wrong, can i easily transfer them back to the old DC ?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have occasionally had issues transferring roles but this was normally due to the state of the DC I was transferring from (USN rollback failure normally).  As long as replication is functioning and there are no other issues with your AD health then you should be fine.  If you do get errors though the operation will fail but remain with the original host. If the roles do not transfer gracefully you can always seize the roles and power off the old DC, but seizing the roles is normally only a step to use in a disaster.

Before that though you probably want to make sure all your DNS and application connections are pointing to your new 2008 DC.

Goes without saying though always have a valid and recent backup before you do anything.  Especially if you only currently have one DC in the domain.